# Python3 UnicodeDecodeError with readlines() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, tweepy, sys

Trying to create a twitter bot that reads lines and posts them. Using Python3 and tweepy, via a virtualenv on my shared server space. This is the part of the code that seems to have trouble:

```
#!/foo/env/bin/python3

import re
import tweepy, time, sys

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])

filename=open(argfile, 'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()
```

this is the error I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error specifically points to `f=filename.readlines()` as the source of the error. Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837421/python-script-receiving-a-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-charact), it has two really helpful answers you should try.

Comment: I have used the encoding encoding='iso-8859-1', It solved my problem

Comment: @hsinghal: ISO-8859-1 (aka latin-1) will always work, but it's often *wrong*. The problem is that it *can* decode any byte from any encoding, but if the original text isn't really latin-1, it's going to decode to garbage. You *need* to know the real encoding, not just guess; UTF-8 is mostly self-checking, so it's unlikely to decode binary gibberish, but latin-1 will happily decode binary gibberish to text gibberish and never whisper a word of complaint.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for your explanation. It adds to my current knowledge.

Answer (score 71):

I think the best answer (in Python 3) is to use the `errors=` parameter:

```
with open('evil_unicode.txt', 'r', errors='replace') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Proof:

```
>>> s = b'\xe5abc\nline2\nline3'
>>> with open('evil_unicode.txt','wb') as f:
...     f.write(s)
...
16
>>> with open('evil_unicode.txt', 'r') as f:
...     lines = f.readlines()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>>> with open('evil_unicode.txt', 'r', errors='replace') as f:
...     lines = f.readlines()
...
>>> lines
['�abc\n', 'line2\n', 'line3']
>>>
```

Note that the `errors=` can be `replace` or `ignore`. Here's what `ignore` looks like:

```
>>> with open('evil_unicode.txt', 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
...     lines = f.readlines()
...
>>> lines
['abc\n', 'line2\n', 'line3']
```

Answer (score 23):

Your default encoding appears to be ASCII, where the input is more than likely UTF-8. When you hit non-ASCII bytes in the input, it's throwing the exception. It's not so much that `readlines` itself is responsible for the problem; rather, it's causing the read+decode to occur, and the decode is failing.

It's an easy fix though; the default `open` in Python 3 allows you to provide the known `encoding` of an input, replacing the default (ASCII in your case) with any other recognized encoding. Providing it allows you to keep reading as `str` (rather than the significantly different raw binary data `bytes` objects), while letting Python do the work of converting from raw disk bytes to true text data:

```
# Using with statement closes the file for us without needing to remember to close
# explicitly, and closes even when exceptions occur
with open(argfile, encoding='utf-8') as inf:
    f = inf.readlines()
```

If the file is some other encoding, you'd change `encoding='utf-8'` to the appropriate argument. Note that while some people will tell you to "Just use `'latin-1'`" here if `'utf-8'` doesn't work":

1. That's often wrong (modern text editors tend to produce UTF-8 or UTF-16, with latin-1 being much less common; frankly, you're more likely to see Microsoft's `'latin-1'` variant, `'cp1252'`, that's mostly the same but remaps some characters to support stuff like smart quotes), and
2. Unlike the UTF encodings, the various byte-per-character ASCII superset encodings (including `'latin-1'`, `'cp1252'`, `'cp437'`, and many others) are not self-checking; if the data isn't in the encoding specified, they'll still happily decode it, it will just produce gibberish for stuff above the ASCII range.

In short, if your data isn't a UTF encoding (or one of the rare non-UTF self-checking encodings), you need to *know* the encoding used, or you're stuck guessing and checking the result to see if it makes sense (and for stuff like a source that might be latin-1 or cp1252, you'll never be sure unless it eventually contains a cp1252-specific character).

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution but I just tried it in python 3.6.8 and it fails.

Comment: @M.H.: It will work *on UTF-8 data*. If it's not UTF-8, you need to figure out what it *is*. This will work just as well on 3.6.8 as on any other 3.x release (and on Python 2.6+ for that matter, if you do `from io import open` to replace the Py2 `open` with the Py3 version). If you don't know the encoding though, you're stuck guessing.

Comment: @r_e_cur: I rejected your edit because, even if your case happened to work with latin-1, latin-1 is a *trap*, and should not be anyone's first (or second, or third) attempt to solve the issue unless they *know*, without a shadow of a doubt, that the source data is *actually* in latin-1. It'll "work" with completely random bytes, and UTF-8 bytes, and UTF-16 bytes; decoding them all as latin-1 will get you a string, but that string will be garbage. UTF-8 is self-checking and therefore any meaningful amount of data will error if it's not *really* UTF-8, making it a much safer choice.

Comment: I did add notes on using it, but rather than including it as a code sample that will be copied and pasted without thinking, I made notes on why *not* to use it, and when you can use it. I strongly suspect latin-1 is wrong for you even if you say it works, because on most Western European Windows systems, cp1252 (which is similar to latin-1, but not exactly the same) is the actual default locale encoding (when the data isn't stored as UTF-16, which most Windows programs use nowadays), and on basically every non-Windows system outside of East Asia (and even some in it), UTF-8 is the default.

Comment: Oh, hmm. Misread, it wasn't r_e_cur who proposed the edit, it was an "anonymous user". I didn't even realize that was a thing on StackOverflow. *shrugs* I'll leave these comments in place if they ever come back to check.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up finding a working answer for myself:

```
filename=open(argfile, 'rb')
```

[This post](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) helped me out a lot.

Comment: If you're actually using Python 3, this is going to dramatically change your behavior; opening in binary mode means not only do you not get line ending translation (admittedly only an issue on Windows), but you get back `bytes` objects instead of `str` (and must manually `decode` them if you want to work with `str`). I posted [an answer that avoids this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35044042/364696) (assuming you know the encoding, which you'd need to know to perform the `decode` anyway).