# Python3 now throwing ASCII error loading data from JSON file

Tags: python, json, load, ascii

I am relatively new to Python and spent at least two hours searching both the internet and now StackOverFlow and could not find out what the problem is here.  My code was working in Python2, now persistent error message below.  I even found this code online for an apparent answer to my question claiming it worked in python3, but it's not for me.  Odd.

```
import json, sys

    with open('2689364.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb6' in position 1938: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can you show us the json file?

Comment: It's long, but below is a chunk of it.  I put it through an online JSON validator, if that means anything.  I was wondering too if somehow it was not a valid JSON file, but it apparently is.

Comment: {
  "resource_uri": "http://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/2689364/",
  "absolute_url": "/opinion/2689364/cook-logothetis-llc-v-king/",
  "cluster": "http://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/clusters/2689364/",
  "author": "http://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/people/8087/",
  "joined_by": [],
  "author_str": "",
  "per_curiam": false,
  "date_created": "2014-08-01T19:36:34.564823Z",
 }

Comment: Which function raise the error? its probably a unicode/bytes encoding error. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837421/python-script-receiving-a-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-charact

Comment: The above is the entire code.  When I comment out the print command, there is no error.  When I try to print(d), I get the error.

Comment: What's *Python* version? Apparently the dict has some non ascii strings inside. Try: `print(repr(d))`.

Comment: Python 3 is the version

Comment: The frustrating thing is that I upgraded to Python 3 and that broke this code.  So, now it's hours and no real answer how to accomplish something that simply worked in Python 2.